# Checkan iterable after expanding the iterations using zip?

Tags: python, list, zip, iterable, try-except

**How to check whether an iterable is the same size after expanding the iterations using zip?** E.g.

```
>>> x = iter([1,2,3])
>>> y = iter([5,6,7,8])
>>> for i,j in zip(x,y):
...     print i,j
... 
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

Doing `next(x)` after using up the iterable throws an error but i can't try-except it since it's not an `Error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

**Is there any way to do the check in a single pass?**

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the remaining values?

Comment: I'm trying to yield out all the remaining values from x or y which haven't be iterated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` also takes a default value so you can simply use that:

```
if next(x, None):
   # x is not empty
```

Just make sure to use a default  that won't be appearing in your iterable.

It is also possible to use `__length_hint__`:

```
In [4]: x = iter([1, 2, 3])

In [5]: y = iter([5, 6, 7, 8])

In [6]: for i, j in zip(x, y):
   ...:         print(i, j)
   ...:     
(1, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 7)

In [7]: x.__length_hint__()
Out[7]: 0

In [8]: y.__length_hint__()
Out[8]: 1
```

Comment: Ahhh, i learn something new from SO everyday. Now I know iterable has `__length_hint__()` and what it does =)

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean you can't try-except?

```
try:
    x.next()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: Ohhhh, `StopIteration` doesn't end with Error but it's still a builtin keyword?

Comment: StopIteration is the exception raised whenever you iterate over an object.
This is the way Python tells you that there are no more items.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, if you are interested in all values from the itreables, you might consider using `itertools.izip_longest` rather than `zip`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = iter([1,2,3])
>>> y = iter([5,6,7,8])
>>> for i, j in itertools.izip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=None):
...     print i, j
...
1 5
2 6
3 7
None 8
```